# Can I ask whether a particular tool exists if I'm having trouble finding it?

Tags: support

I know that shopping recommendations are banned, but is it OK to give a feature list and then ask if a tool exists that satisfies them all? I'm not asking for a specific make and model, merely if it exists in the real world or just in my imagination.

I've spent fruitless hours searching online and I'm starting to doubt if it exists. I would just like to know if I should continue looking or just abandon the search and start considering alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to show pictures of or describe a particular application that may require a tool and then inquire as to what tool type would be used for that application. This way the information that would come in answers is more universal and of longer lasting usefulness to folks who come to this site for help.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how I could do it in this particular case... Ok, I'll give the details, perhaps you'll have an idea. I'm looking for a vacuum cleaner, but one that would be comfortable to use both for diy projects and daily household use. The first requires the ability to vacuum fine dust (like plaster) and slightly wet things, the second requires a long, retractable cable and a low center of gravity. And this is the combination that I haven't been able to find.

Comment: @Vilx- It's also a combination that's not easy to search on. I'm sure it exists, it's basically a multi-setting vacuum, but finding it...

Comment: @Mast - Exactly. I haven't been able to come up with the right keywords yet.